# C# to JavaScript Serialization issue

Tags: c#, javascript, serialization

I am trying to dynamically pass a double array from C# to some JavaScript code. Here's how I am doing it now:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsLat = serializer.Serialize(lat);
```

I then call `InvokeScript` with `jsLat` as parameter.

When I try `lat.length` on the JS side, I get the correct length, but when I try to do `lat[#]` all the values come back as undefined.

Also, when I do `alert(lat.valueOf())` I see all the values.

Why are all the values coming back as undefined?

Comment: What `lat[#]` is supposed to be? It is not a valid js code.

Comment: # is any valid index (to be completely clear: lay[0], lat[1] ...)

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you mean the serializer output, it looks something like this: "[1234.556458654, 345738.2345365465, ...]".

Comment: This is JSON. You need to unserialize it in js. Also there's no index access for strings in js.

Comment: Is there a builtin way to deserialize it? (this is the 2nd week I am working with JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function on JavaScript side supported by all modern browsers. Unless you need to support IE7/IE6 it is built in function, for IE6/7 there are JavaScript implementations (check out http://json.org for details).

```
  var result = JSON.parse("{lat:1234, lon:567"})
```

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) that supports all browsers.

Comment: The jQuery bit did the trick, thanks. I am surprised C# has no direct way of doing this operation.

Comment: @user472875, C# **does not** run in browser... And C# does have de-serialization of JSON in JavaScriptSerializer if needed server side.

Comment: I meant something more like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication#patjs

Comment: Since you did not mention the fact that you need it for WebBrowser control nor added tag for it it made an answer much more generic. Your link seem to provide good way of doing it for WebBrowser case (convert it to C# if needed).